# Use mapkit to calculate driving distance between two addresses?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

Is it possible to use the mapkit in the iphone sdk to calculate driving distance between two addresses ?

Answer (score 3):

How about using the Core Location framework:

`- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location`

You'll need the latitude/longitudes for both addresses.

Edit: Deprecated in iOS 3.2. Use the `distanceFromLocation:` method instead.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the fallback solutions. But as I said before I would like to have the driving distance not just the distance between 2 locations.

The question remains, is there a way to get the location from the mapkit ? Like I enter a address and it gives me the location ?

Comment: Revisiting this question, it's not explicitly stated that you want the driving distance between 2 addresses. I'd suggest updating the question.

Comment: Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

With iOS7 you [get full directions within the API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW5)

Take a look at this tutorial [Tutorial](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/08/ios7-day-by-day-day-13-route-directions-with-mapkit/).

Answer (score 1):

No but if you have the longitude/latitude then it is fairly easy to calculate the distance. It is the mathematical distance between those points of course. Not the actual driving or walking distance that is based on an actual route.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I need the driving distance. I do not need to display it, just get the distance.

Answer (score 0):

In my applications I used MKDirections to get driving (walking) distance between two location.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoordinates = YOUR_START_COORDINATES;
CLLocationCoordinate2D endCoordinates = YOUR_END_COORDINATES;

MKPlacemark *startPoint = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:startCoordinates];
MKPlacemark *endPoint = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:endCoordinates];

MKMapItem *startItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:startPoint];
MKMapItem *endItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:endPoint];

MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];

request.source = startItem;
request.destination = endItem;
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile; //here you can choose a transport type you need

MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

          if (response) {
              for (MKRoute *route in response.routes) {
                  NSLog(@"Distance : %f", route.distance);
              }
          }

 }];
```

if you have you location as an address, so you can use the method of CLGeocoder, which will give you latitude and longitude of your address

```
- (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

If you compare a driving distance result using MKDirections with the one using Google Maps, you will see that they differ. I was searching regarding this matter and came across the following link http://www.macworld.co.uk/review/reference-education/apple-maps-vs-google-maps-3464377/

Even though Apple have been improving their map service, they still concede in accuracy to Google (IMO), at least in a question regarding the driving distance.
So if accuracy is not highly important in your case, so you can follow along with Apple. Otherwise I would recommend checking Google API.